# .net Code Issue with binding chart

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was trying to bind the telerik chart with below code, then it is thoughing an error as per the screen shot.

any one have idea how handle this error.

Logic explanation: Am assigning the data table as **listdata** datasource and trying to bind the data based on table rows count.

```
Dim listdata As new DataList 
        listdata.DataSource   = ds.Tables.Item(0)

        BaselineRadChart.Clear()    
        Dim chartSeries As New ChartSeries("Baseline", ChartSeriesType.Line) 
            chartSeries.Appearance.ShowLabels = False
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            While i < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
                chartSeries.AddItem(New ChartSeriesItem(listData[i].x, listData[i].y))
                i = i + 1
            End While  

            BaselineRadChart.AddChartSeries(chartSeries)
            BaselineRadChart.ChartTitle.TextBlock.Text = title
            BaselineRadChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = xaxislableName
            BaselineRadChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = True
            BaselineRadChart.PlotArea.XAxis.IsZeroBased = False
            BaselineRadChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = yaxislableName
            BaselineRadChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = True
            BaselineRadChart.PlotArea.YAxis.IsZeroBased = True
```

I was trying to develop the above code by using the below reference code(bcz we same same functionality, if the below code works, definately my code works). It is working for him.

```
ChartSeries chartSeries = new ChartSeries("Altitude", ChartSeriesType.Line); 
chartSeries.Appearance.ShowLabels = false; 
incrementCount = 1; 

for (int i = 0; i < listData.Count; i = i + incrementCount) 
    {
        chartSeries.AddItem(new ChartSeriesItem(listData[i].x, listData[i].y)); 
    }

RadChart2.AddChartSeries(chartSeries);
RadChart2.ChartTitle.TextBlock.Text = title;
RadChart2.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = 
"Distance (Miles)"; 
RadChart2.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = true; 
RadChart2.PlotArea.XAxis.IsZeroBased = true; 
RadChart2.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = yAxisLabel;
RadChart2.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = true; 
RadChart2.PlotArea.YAxis.IsZeroBased = false;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to pull the data from the table?

```
While i < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    chartSeries.AddItem(New ChartSeriesItem(_
        ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("x"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("y")))
    '               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ get from the tabel
    i = i + 1
End While
```

Comment: That is what my understanding. I tried that code too. didn't work for me. Actually, I was fallowing a reference code to implement my development. FYI, I have updated my post with my reference code too. Do you have any idea what he is doing with in that code. Thank You